# Bloated codebase - are there third party implementations of the tor protocol?

Tags: source-code, implementations

Are there third party implementation of tor that perhaps don't implement the entirety of the protocol? But can interact with the tor network.

It really isn't practical to audit this for an individual: (output from cloc on current tor git)

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                      files          blank        comment           code
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C                               583          47084          64919         270594
C/C++ Header                    516           7253          17573          29573
Markdown                         98           1882              0           5369
Python                           46           1410           1650           4873
make                             83            562            275           3295
m4                                6            427            152           3045
Bourne Shell                     49            685            911           2856
Rust                             26            582           1239           2538
Perl                              9             66             90            433
HTML                              1             21             14            276
YAML                              3             40            143            252
Bourne Again Shell                3             51             95            168
TOML                             10             40             38            153
PHP                               1             20              0            114
Lua                               4             27             10             77
Ruby                              1             18             34             63
CSS                               1              2              0              8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                           1440          60170          87143         323687
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a list of third-party Tor implementations here (note that many/most are not actively developed): https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/ListOfTorImplementations

You may also be interested in looking at [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/), which is typically used for controlling existing Tor clients/relays, but it has a lot of functionality for interacting with the network directly.

Comment: I see. I was more hoping for something serious written C that follows the unix philosophy. I guess I will just have to tear apart the codebase into something minimal and study that.

Comment: @JohnSmith I'm not aware of anything like that. The tor codebase is large with many interconnected pieces, although they're working on trying to make it more modular (but this process will likely continue for several years).